# Позиционирование вершин в sigma.js графе

Tags: javascript, графы

Господа, добрый день.

Ситуация следующая, есть граф смежности сетевых устройств (маршрутизаторов), который рисуется с помощью: `sigma.js`
Информация о вершинах получаю из базы данных, после `PHP` скриптом отправляется в браузер в виде `json`.

Каждая вершина имеет вид:

```
{id: host, label: host, x: Math.random(), y: Math.random(), size: 1, color: '#3399FF'}
```

Где `id` и `label` - хостнейм конкретного маршрутизатора.

Не понимание ситуации, у меня возникло, касательно позиции вершин:
В моем случае, позиции `x` и `y` вычисляются с помощью функции `Math.random()`, 
что помогает как то раскидать вершины по экрану. В произвольном порядке.

Моя цель, сохранить позицию вершины после перетаскивания ее левой клавишей мыши.
В идеале отправить эту информацию в БД.

Прежде всего, у меня возникла тотальное непонимание, как это реализовать.

В больших интернетах есть много способов, которые помогают вернуть позицию курсора в момент л.клика.
Но касательно позиции элемента и как текущую позицию куда ни будь записать для дебага, мне пока не ясно.

Если есть идеи в какую сторону гуглить/читать, касательно реализации данного функционала - буду благодарен.

Comment: Как я понял, Вам нужно реализовать обработчики событий mousedown и mouseup на том элементе, где происходит отрисовка сетки. См https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent, и например http://javascript.info/tutorial/mouse-events

Comment: Спасибо, в принципе тоже вариант. Так же ребята с js форума подсказали отследить событие dragend встроенными средствами  sigma.js. В моем случае это более подходящий вариант.